# UICollectionView with custom layout - how/where to add a supplementary view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm working with an example of [Circle Layout](https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout), using UICollectionView with a custom layout class defined in the storyboard.

**Is there some sort of a tutorial or a step by step explanation of how to add a supplementary view over to a collection view that uses a custom layout?**

I've been looking at the [Introducing Collection Views](https://github.com/mpospese/IntroducingCollectionViews) example, but cannot really understand how supplementary views are defined in that project. It appears that they are registered in a storyboard using flow layout, but I'm at a loss as to how subsequent layout changes in that project move supplementary views around.

Comment: this tutorial should help you answer your question http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Comment: Use this link to learn UICollectionVIewLayout http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that you return `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the supplementary views in `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)`. For example, in your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass:

```
var headerAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!

override func prepare() {
    headerAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(
        forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
        with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
    headerAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    if headerAttributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
        return [headerAttributes]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The important part is that the attributes are created using the `forSupplementaryViewOfKind:` initialiser. By returning attributes for supplementary views from this method the collection view knows that these views exist and where they are positioned and will call `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)` to get the actual view from its data source.

Comment: This was pretty correct , I spend around 1 hr for this solution thank you so much .